# Handling a disabled azure key vault secret using go azure sdk?

Tags: go, azure-keyvault, azure-sdk, autorest

I am trying an extend Kubernetes operator written in Go to handle Azure Key Vault Secrets that have been disabled. The operator is using the Azure SDK for Go as well as the Azure autorest library.

I am very new to Go and I'm struggling to populate the [ServiceError](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/Azure/go-autorest/autorest/azure#ServiceError) struct when there is an error

The snippet of code I'm looking at is this: (see in [context](https://github.com/ForgeRock/secret-agent/blob/fea92ec88669aba4fbc072a331124bafee4bb1ce/pkg/secretsmanager/secretsmanager.go#L510-L516))

```golang
    response, err := sm.client.GetSecret(ctx, fmt.Sprintf(azureVaultURLFmt, sm.azureVaultName), secretID, "")
    if err != nil {
        if e, ok := err.(autorest.DetailedError); ok && e.StatusCode.(int) == 404 {
            return []byte{}, nil
        }
        return []byte{}, err
    }
```

At present it handles missing secrets as noted by the 404 http status code.  However I want to handle the error situation when you read a disabled secret which surfaces as a 403, and with extra error information in the `ServiceError`. However, no matter what I try I haven't managed to figure out how to get at the [ServiceError](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/Azure/go-autorest/autorest/azure#ServiceError) struct.

I tried doing:

```golang
        if e, ok := err.(azure.ServiceError); ok {
            log.V(0).Info("Go an azure service error")
            return []byte{}, nil
        }
```

But the code is never called.

Using the original code, I attached the delve debugger with vscode, and I can see that the `e` variable had an extra hidden `data` variable that appeared to contain both the `ServiceError` and `DetailedError` struct, but I just can't get at the `ServiceError`.

The [DetailedError](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/Azure/go-autorest/autorest@v0.11.24#DetailedError) struct has a `ServiceError` byte array on it. Am I supposed to manually call `UnmarshallJSON` or something like that? I think it's supposed to magically do it for me somehow, but I'm just not sure how.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed to find a workaround by using a debugger and inspecting the `err` object. It isn't particularly pretty, but it does work.

```golang
    response, err := sm.client.GetSecret(ctx, fmt.Sprintf(azureVaultURLFmt, sm.azureVaultName), secretID, "")
    if err != nil {
        // We can ignore some errors
        if de, ok := err.(autorest.DetailedError); ok {
            if re, ok := de.Original.(*azure.RequestError); ok {
                if re.ServiceError.Code == "SecretNotFound" {
                    // Secret not existing is fine, as that means we will create a new secret
                    return []byte{}, nil
                } else if code, ok := re.ServiceError.InnerError["code"].(string); ok && code == "SecretDisabled" {
                    // Disabled secret also fine, as it means we will create a new version of the secret
                    return []byte{}, nil
                }
            }
        }
        return []byte{}, err
    }
```